# Using str_extract to extract dollar amounts

Tags: r, stringr

I have a column of text and would like to extract just the dollar amount contained in the string, using the dollar sign as the start of the string. I can match the dollar sign, but am not sure how to then take the numbers directly after (and remove commas).

I've tried using the dollar sign as an anchor in str_extract but am not getting just the full dollar amount.

```
input <- (c("the sum of $175,000,000 and the sum", "the sum of $20,000,000 and the sum", "the sum of $100,000,000 and the sum"))

df<-as.data.frame(input)

df %>% 
    mutate(amount = str_extract(input,"^\\$"))
```

run before the mutate it looks like:

```
input
the sum of $175,000,000 and the sum
the sum of $20,000,000 and the sum
the sum of $100,000,000 and the sum
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
input                                         amount
the sum of $175,000,000 and the sum        175000000
the sum of $20,000,000 and the sum          20000000
the sum of $100,000,000 and the sum        100000000
```

Comment: Are you definitely never going to have any decimal values? That would affect whether you should be removing `.`

Answer (score 4):

Using the helper function `parse_number` from `readr` you can do

```
df %>% 
  mutate(amount = parse_number(str_match(input,"\\$([0-9,.]+)")[,2]))
```

Basically we use `str_match` to strip off the "$" and then pass the rest through `parse_number` to make it numeric. This will also work with values like "$11.11"

You can also use the base function `as.numeric()` rather than `parse_number` but thought I would suggest it if you are using other tidyverse packages.

Comment: When I use this, I get the following error: Error: Column `amount` must be length 1 (the group size), not 3. The actual column for input is much longer than the simple example I have here...could this possibly be related to other numbers that might be in the column?

Comment: @skl I would expect you to get that error without the `[,2]` part. `str_match()` returns a matrix but we want the second column. This worked for me with the sample. It would be helpful to have a more representative example that triggers the error to say for sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
library(stringr)

input <- (c("the sum of $175,000,000 and the sum", "the sum of $20,000,000 and the sum", "the sum of $100,000,000 and the sum"))

df<-as.data.frame(input)

#extract the $, the digits and commas
#then remove the $ and commas
df %>% mutate(amount = str_remove_all(str_extract(input,"\\$[0-9,]+"), "[\\$,]"))
```

Comment: When I use this, I get the following error: Error: Column amount must be length 1 (the group size), not 3. The actual column for input is much longer than the simple example I have here...could this possibly be related to other numbers that might be in the column?

Comment: In your example, input was a provide as a vector. If your actual data structure is different, then it may cause the error you experienced.  An actual sample of your data avoids these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
gsub(",", "", sub(".*[$]([0-9,]+)\\s*.*", "\\1", input))
#[1] "175000000" "20000000"  "100000000"
```